# How to find empty directories in Windows using a Powershell Script

Tags: windows, powershell

What command do you use to find empty directories in Windows?

Some folders might contain some hidden folders like `.svn` or `.settings`, but they should still be treated as empty folders.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is with a small [PowerShell script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730953.aspx). If you're running Windows 7 you should have it installed already, if not visit Microsoft.com to download and install it. The link provides a detailed description but the gist of the operation is included here for your convenience.

Open PowerShell and enter this:

```
(gci C:\Scripts -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ? {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | select FullName
```

Change C:\Scripts to whatever you want to search through, you can even set it to just C:\ if you want it to check the entire drive.

It will give you output like this (note these are the empty directories below C:\Scripts.

```
FullName
------- 
C:\Scripts\Empty 
C:\Scripts\Empty Folder 2 
C:\Scripts\Empty\Empty Subfolder 
C:\Scripts\New Folder\Empty Subfolder Three Levels Deep
```

If you look into PowerShell a bit I'm sure you'll be able to figure out how to automatically delete empty folders if you want to (though I recommend against it, just in case.)

**Edit**: As Richard mentioned in the comments, for a truly empty directory use. It searches for hidden files and folders too:

```
(gci C:\Scripts -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ?{$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0} | select FullName
```

Comment: am using Windows Vista

Comment: PowerShell for Vista can be downloaded here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23200

Comment: Note: that pipeline will find folders that contain no files but do contain other folders. To have completely empty folders change third element of the pipe to `?{$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0}`.

Comment: Good catch @Richard, I probably should have noticed that since it demonstrates it in the example output!

Comment: PS C:\> (gci C:\Scripts -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ? {$_.GetFiles().
Count -eq 0}| select FullName
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Scripts' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:5
+ (gci <<<<  C:\Scripts -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ? {$_.GetFiles()
.Count -eq 0}| select FullName
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Scripts:String) [Get-ChildIt
   em], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: It seems to be failig for me and I am not that proficient with these scripts, what did I do wrong?

Comment: @Joshua, you didn't change "C:\Scripts" to where you want to search, hence you get the error "Cannot find path 'C:\Scripts' because it does not exist." It's right at the start of the line.

Comment: apologize, didn't realize that the input was part of the script. It seems to work now, but it shows "..." at the end of the results, is there a way to show just the file name instead

Comment: @Joshua, you should only see "..." if the path is too long to fit in the window (which there will be a number of instances of.) You can increase the width of the PowerShell window by right clicking the title bar, choosing properties and going to the layout tab. Here increase the screen buffer and window size widths and re-run the command.

Comment: @Windos - script seems to work fine. Just realized that I would need this check only on the leaf nodes (i.e. last directories) currently it shows a directory as empty even if its not the leaf node.

Comment: @Joshua, have you read Richards comment (third one in this thread) and my edit to the answer? That should only give you directories with no files and no child directories (i.e. the leaf nodes)

Comment: `(gci C:\Scripts -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ? {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | select FullName`  If you change to `(gci C:\Scripts -r -Directory | ? {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | select FullName`, this will perform faster due to removing one of the pipeline phases.  Only works PS v3 and later.

Comment: If you know PowerShell this isn't hard to do with the example, but I came here wanting to find the inverse of what this question was, namely I wanted to find directories that did have files or other directories in them. I removed the -r as I only cared about the top level dirs. and changed the -eq 0 to -gt 0. To do that, you can make a minor change to this answer to get that:  (gci C:\scripts\ | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ?{$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -gt 0} |select FullName

Comment: i think there is a missing bracket in the final solution

Answer (score 10):

The following is the easiest way I could find to achieve this with a single line of code. It lists the empty directories at the current location. If recursion is needed the parameter`-Recurse` could be added to the call to `Get-ChildItem`.

`Get-ChildItem -Directory | Where-Object { $_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0 }`

Short version with aliases:

`dir -Directory | ? {$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0 }`

Or, as a parameterized PowerShell function (I added this to my PowerShell startup profile):

```
Function Get-EmptyDirectories($basedir) { 
    Get-ChildItem -Directory $basedir | Where-Object { $_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0 }
}
```

This can then be invoked as any other PowerShell function, including piping. For example, this call would delete all empty directories in the system temp directory:

`Get-EmptyDirectories $env:TMP | del`

Comment: At least in powershell 5, symlinks/junctions i.e. with `[System.IO.FileAttributes]:: ReparsePoint` are returned by `Get-ChildItem -Directory` but they don't have method `GetFileSystemInfos()` causing an error. Filter those out with: `$_.Attributes -eq [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Directory` removes any entry with `ReparsePoint` flag enum set.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, I used this as a basis for my script. I wanted to delete empty folders but trying to do `Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0}` would delete folders that had sub-directories that were not empty. I ended up using a DO WHILE loop to remove a folder that had no files or folders then loop back and check again until it reached the end of the tree.

```
$Datefn=Get-Date -format M.d.yyyy_HH.mm.ss
#Set The File Name for the log file
$DelFileName = $Datefn
#Set The File Ext for the log file
$DelFileExt = " - Old Files" + ".log"
#Set The File Name With Ext for the log file
$DelFileName = $DelFileName + $DelFileExt
#Set Log Path
$LogPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$Path = 'Q:\'
$NumDays = 365
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Exclude DCID.txt,*.exe -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -lt`
(Get-Date).addDays(-$NumDays) -and $_.psiscontainer -eq $false} |
    ForEach-Object  {
        $properties = @{`
            Path = $_.Directory`
            Name = $_.Name
            DateModified = $_.LastWriteTime
            Size = $_.Length / 1GB  }
    New-Object PSObject -Property $properties | select Path,Name,DateModified, Size
    } |
    Out-File "$LogPath\$DelFileName"
<#
#Removes the files found
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Exclude DCID.txt,*.exe -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -lt`
(Get-Date).addDays(-365) -and $_.psiscontainer -eq $false} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
#Removes empty folders
DO {
$a = (Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}) | Where-Object`
{$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0} | Select-Object Fullname
$a
(Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}) | Where-Object`
{$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Force
}
WHILE ($a -ne $null)
#>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {!$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count}
```

The count is not 0, it doesn't exist at all meaning that the directory is completely empty or holds other completely empty folders

Answer (score 0):

Combination of a couple answers above but if anyone needs to loop through the empty dirs

```
foreach($emptyDir in Get-ChildItem $outputdir -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {!$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count} | select FullName)
{
    Write-Host $emptyDir.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to find and **delete**/**remove** the empty folders you can use this one-liner (a bit hardcore though... **use with caution and good backups**!). It will printout what folders it deleted. Sometimes a couple of empty folders are left after execution, and you have to run the one-liner several times to delete all empty folders.

```
(gci "E:\Backup P4\Bilder\Junkmappar" -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ?{$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0} | select FullName | ? {$_.fullname} | Remove-Item -path {$_.fullname} -force -verbose
```

...and of course replace my example path before running!

Answer (score 0):

I think this calls for recursion...

```
Function Remove-EmptyPath
{
    Param(
        [Parameter( Mandatory )]
        [String[]] $Path
    )
    Process{
        ForEach ( $LitPath in ( Resolve-Path $Path ))
        {
            ForEach ( $subDir in ( Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $LitPath -ad -Force ))
            {
                Remove-EmptyPath $subDir.FullName
            }
            If ( ! ( Get-Item -LiteralPath $LitPath -Force).GetFileSystemInfos() )
            {
                Write-Verbose ( "Deleting directory: '$LitPath'" )
                Remove-Item -LiteralPath $LitPath -Force
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage:

`Remove-EmptyPath .`            # Current directory
`Remove-EmptyPath . -Verbose`   # List deleted direcotries

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using GetFileSystemInfos + [Select-Object with Format-Table (fix truncated output)](https://superuser.com/a/1049648/1045881)

```sh
(gci "C:\Scripts" -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ? {$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0} | Select-Object FullName | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Also use gci `""` [with quotation marks when specifying long filenames or paths with spaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/filenames-with-spaces-require-quotation-mark)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).