# How to fix truncated PowerShell output, even when I've specified -width 300

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, path

I'm trying to get a list of all the directories and files on an external hard drive, with one fully-qualified directory/file path per line. I'm using PowerShell on Windows 10 to achieve this. This is the PowerShell command I'm using:

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\' -Force -Recurse | Select-Object FullName | Out-File -Encoding utf8 "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\listing.txt" -width 300
```

However, some paths are being truncated in my output. In fact, over 10,000 lines are truncated. Here is an example of one line in my listing.txt PowerShell output file:

```
E:\Sort\Tech Stuff\2006-2007 CompanyLtd\fsie01-Engineering-Users-User1\Reference\LCID & Language Group by Language\Configuring and Using International Features of Windows Windows 2000 - List of Locale I...
```

When I browse to this directory in File Explorer (E:\Sort\Tech Stuff\2006-2007 CompanyLtd\fsie01-Engineering-Users-User1\Reference\LCID & Language Group by Language), the file there is called 'Configuring and Using International Features of Windows Windows 2000 - List of Locale IDs and Language Groups.url'. The path of this file is 228 characters long if I haven't miscounted, which should be within acceptable limits.

What am I doing wrong that is truncating the paths in my PowerShell output?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Pipe output to [Format-Table](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=293962) commandlet, e.g. as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\' -Force -Recurse | Select-Object FullName | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

or

```
(Get-ChildItem 'E:\' -Force -Recurse).FullName | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Note that `-Width` parameter of `Out-File` cmdlet specifies the number of characters in each line of output. Any additional characters are truncated, not wrapped. However, `-Width 300` should suffice in this case.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to allow me to get the output I want. However, there's still no explanation as to what was wrong with my initial command, which looks like it should do what I want. Any idea? It's not intuitive that paths would be (apparently arbitrarily) truncated at ~205 characters unless one uses a format-table command.

Comment: For me `Format-Table -AutoSize` didn't help and strings were truncated anyway, whilst `-width 300` did

Comment: I had to use `Format-Table -Wrap -Autosize` for my case; was still getting truncated column values in multiple columns of output even after using `Format-Table -Autosize`

Comment: I can confirm that `-Autosize` on its own does nothing much different in my case either, `Format-Table -Wrap -Autosize` is probably going the be the better solution.

Answer (score 10):

First you need to make sure Select-Object is not truncated, by using ExpandProperty for a single property

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\' -Force -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Out-File -Encoding utf8 "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\listing.txt"
```

Or by pipe to format-table when there are more properties.
Format-table will select values to display if there is not space enough in console, even with parameters autosize and wrap.
So you will need to pipe to Out-String with width parameter to see it all in console or add width to Out-File to see it all in output file.

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\' -Force -Recurse | Select-Object * | Format-Table | Out-String -width 9999
```

and (

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\' -Force -Recurse | Select-Object * | Format-Table | Out-File -width 9999 -Encoding utf8 "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\listing.txt"
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\' -Force -Recurse | Select-Object * | Format-Table | Out-String -width 9999 | Out-File -Encoding utf8 "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\listing.txt"
```

)
When values are in a collection/array the output is controlled by $FormatEnumerationLimit
Setting it to -1 means unlimited.

I know this is an old post, but I found it before the answer I was looking for.
So thought I would share my findings.

Comment: Doesnt Out-File support width too so you could forgo the Out-String?

Comment: @Marie Sure, I have edited my answer so you can see the variations.

Comment: This is my preferred solution as I'll remember it. Top tip...

Answer (score 6):

for me it works best with piping to  `export-csv`

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Export-Csv?view=powershell-3.0

simply:

```
GCI 'E:\' -Recurse | Select FullName | Export-CSV Files.csv
```

without double quotes:

```
Add-Content -Path Files.txt -Value (GCI 'E:\' -Recurse).FullName
```

Comment: That works, but each line gets enclosed in double quotes.  So you'll have to deal with that if you don't want them.

Comment: @CharlesBurge I think it depends on the culture and white space. But  see my edit for a workaround.

Comment: @CharlesBurge To get ride of double quotes, just use `-UseQuotes Never` in the Export-CSV command.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

---

You need to mash the answers from andreaswbj & josefz together to do what I think you are trying to do.

---

```
PS:\> $FormatEnumerationLimit = -1   
PS:\> $Console = $Host.UI.RawUI 
PS:\> $Buffer = $Console.BufferSize  
PS:\> $Buffer.Width = '4096'
PS:\> $Console.BufferSize = $Buffer 
PS:\> $Var = [PsCustomObject]@{Stdout = $("*"*1024)} 
PS:\> $Var

Stdout
------
****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************


PS:\>
```

Answer (score 3):

Following helped me:

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit=-1

Your Command | Format-Table | Out-File -width 999999 -Encoding utf8 "C:\Temp\result.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use ConvertTo-Csv (just the same as Export-Csv but does not send to file) as you can easily continue to manipulate the results as required.

`gci 'C:\Program Files\'`

`gci 'C:\Program Files\' | Select Mode,LastWriteTime,Length,Name | ConvertTo-Csv`

This now *guarantees* that you have strings (not objects!) and that none of the data has been truncated, so you can continue to use any other string manipulations that you want:

`gci 'C:\Program Files\' | Select Name | ConvertTo-Csv | Select-String "Win"`

`(gci 'C:\Program Files\' | Select Name | ConvertTo-Csv) -Replace """", ""`

Second one gets rid of the " characters added by CSV encoding.

**Notes:**

The `<verb>-Csv` Cmdlets will output *all* Property types (AliasProperty, NoteProperty, Property, ScriptProperty, etc). You can easily check that with:

`gci 'C:\Program Files\' | Get-Member *Property`

Also recommend using the `-No (-NoTypeInformation)` switch to get rid of the `#TYPE Selected.System.IO.DirectoryInfo` that is at the top of all outputs.

You always guarantee that you are working with non-truncated values with this method. With this I can usually organise the information that I need before throwing out to a file or screen.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and it was due to errors in the output.

added **-ErrorAction:silentlyContinue** and output is displayed properly.

Comment: could you elaborate on this a little more?

Answer (score -2):

It will only work if the output is tableview. If the output is listview it's not going to work.

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\' -Force -Recurse | Select-Object FullName | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Read More Here: [Fix Powershell Truncated Output](https://mcsaguru.com/powershell-output-truncated/)

Comment: This appears to just be the exact same solution as the accepted solution (from 4 years ago). Please be sure to read existing answers before posting a new one to ensure you avoid duplicate of content.