# How to fix truncated PowerShell output in a SHA256 recursive file listing?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a recursive file listing of a specific folder, with SHA256 hash of the individual files, using the following PowerShell script

```
Get-ChildItem "." -File -Recurse -Name | Foreach-Object { Get-FileHash -Path $($_) -Algorithm SHA256 } > sha256.txt
```

However, the output in sha256.txt is truncated at 185 characters. How do I extend that so output isn't truncated?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest piping out to "export-csv sha256.csv -append -notypeinformation". Expand property and FT wrap etc work in the console however they dont when writing to txt file, however outputting to CSV overcomes this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix truncated PowerShell output, even when I've specified -width 300](https://superuser.com/questions/1049531/how-to-fix-truncated-powershell-output-even-when-ive-specified-width-300)

Answer (score 1):

For this query, Powershell will output to a table, same as doing a SQL `SELECT` from the command line would.  The table is limited by the console window size (I think), even when redirecting to an output file, or using `Out-File`.  We need to tell Powershell to use longer line lengths, and auto fit the columns for good measure.  Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "." -File -Recurse -Name | Foreach-Object { Get-FileHash -Path $($_) -Algorithm SHA256 } | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath sha256.txt -Width 300
```

Adjust the value of "300" as necessary.

Credit: https://superuser.com/a/1049648/332540

Answer (score 0):

Redirection ('**>**') and **Out-File** both recirect output that has been formatted for the console (hence truncated...). Use [Set-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7) instead:

The difference is most easily seen with **gci**:

```
gci > gci.txt
```

Produces:
[image]

Whereas:

```
gci > set-content
```

Produces:
[image]

Also, there's no need for **ForEach**, **Get-FileHasn** takes pipleine input. So "cleaner" code would be:

```
(gci -file -name) | Get-FileHash | set-content hasn.txt
```

The parenthesis are only necessary if the output file is being created in the same location as the files being processed. Otherwise, an error will be thrown when **Get-FileHash** tries to access the output file.