# Powershell truncates my output, how do I make it NEVER do that?

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-terminal

Sometimes powershell commands produce output which is wider than the console window. When this happens, it collapses extra content into a "..." so everything fits in the width of the console.

Here's an example with the command `get-filehash` but the problem applies to any command with wide output, I guess:
[image: example of truncated powershell command output]

If I make the screen wider, it does NOT fill in the content that was missing before. Instead, I have to make the screen wider and then run the command AGAIN, and hope that I made the console "wide enough". This is super annoying if the command takes a long time. Look...
[image: console screen STILL NOT WIDE ENOUGH!]

Is there a way I can force powershell to *always* give me a non-truncated version of my output?

If possible, I would like to configure it to do that BY DEFAULT so that I don't have to remember to pipe it to yet another verbose hard-to-remember commandlet.

...**update**...
According to a suggestion in the comments, I tried to pipe to `Ft -wrap -autosize`, but that still has problems, and I would have to remember to type "`Ft -wrap -autosize`"

[image: still a problem]

...**update2**...
So far one of the options from @postanote answer using `| Format-List -Force` seems to be the best. It requires the least amount of memorization and guessing...
[image: much better now!]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix truncated PowerShell output, even when I've specified -width 300](https://superuser.com/questions/1049531/how-to-fix-truncated-powershell-output-even-when-ive-specified-width-300)

Comment: [powershell - Prevent PowerGUI from truncating the output - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158142/prevent-powergui-from-truncating-the-output)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, not really. I don't want to guess how long the output is going to be nor do I want to be forced to remember to pipe to anything.  "| Ft -autosize -wrap" *almost* does it.

Comment: What I would like to do is to *change* the default behavior. Possibly with some env variable setting (unfortunately the SO suggest with $FormatEnumerationLimit=-1  didn't work). It's just bizarre to me that this is the default behavior. If anything, I would expect that forcing the output to fit exactly within the width of the console should be something that would require an option or post-processing.

Comment: PS will always use a table if the count of values returned is 5 or less and truncate it to fit whatever screen width/buffer you are using. Also, look at the other Format-* cmdlets. Remember, your data attributes will change depending on what you are after, so, you cannot depend/default to/on one format type.

Comment: PowerShell uses profiles to load session preferences each time it starts. You write any customizations into that profile file and they'll be present each time you run PS without having to modify defaults or system behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screen buffer and PS default formatter are your root cause for this.

Don't display as the default, a table.
Instead, force it as a list or use a custom wrap function/module.

```
# PS Default formatting
Get-FileHash -Path 'J:\MSBuild2018\BRK2100 .NET Overview & Roadmap-BRK2100_3000.mp4' -Algorithm SHA512
# Results
<#
Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path                                                                     
---------       ----                                                                   ----                                                                     
SHA512          3C174CDB0D322382028F47635D8D929AD052360093423C9031B35D1870271146381... J:\MSBuild2018\BRK2100 .NET Overview & Roadmap-BRK2100_3000.mp4  
#>

# Select the properties you want - PS Default formatting
Get-FileHash -Path 'J:\MSBuild2018\BRK2100 .NET Overview & Roadmap-BRK2100_3000.mp4' -Algorithm SHA512 | 
Select-Object -Property Algorithm, Hash
# Results
<#
Algorithm Hash                                                                                                                            
--------- ----                                                                                                                            
SHA512    3C174CDB0D322382028F47635D8D929AD052360093423C9031B35D187027114638128E62156DCC8ABFB35464F2A5B5F460993915F7E1B35A7885B0C3C0D5A699
#>

# Use List formatting
Get-FileHash -Path 'J:\MSBuild2018\BRK2100 .NET Overview & Roadmap-BRK2100_3000.mp4' -Algorithm SHA512 | 
Format-List -Force
# Results
<#
Algorithm : SHA512
Hash      : 3C174CDB0D322382028F47635D8D929AD052360093423C9031B35D187027114638128E62156DCC8ABFB35464F2A5B5F460993915F7E1B35A7885B0C3C0D5A699
Path      : J:\MSBuild2018\BRK2100 .NET Overview & Roadmap-BRK2100_3000.mp4
#>

Get-FileHash -Path 'J:\MSBuild2018\BRK2100 .NET Overview & Roadmap-BRK2100_3000.mp4' -Algorithm SHA512 | 
Select-Object -Property Algorithm, Hash, Path | 
Format-List -Force
# Results
<#
Algorithm : SHA512
Hash      : 3C174CDB0D322382028F47635D8D929AD052360093423C9031B35D187027114638128E62156DCC8ABFB35464F2A5B5F460993915F7E1B35A7885B0C3C0D5A699
Path      : J:\MSBuild2018\BRK2100 .NET Overview & Roadmap-BRK2100_3000.mp4
#>

Find-Module -Name '*wrap*'

# Results
<#
Version              Name                                Repository           Description                                                                       
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                       
...
1.0.1                TextWrapping                        PSGallery            Commands for wrapping and unwrapping text.                                        
...
1.0.1                FormatWrap                          PSGallery            Formats the output as a text wrapping string.                                     
...#>
```

Comment: Thanks!  just piping to "Format-List -Force" does the trick for me. It doesn't require selecting the names of the output objects and doesn't require me to specify a width. I can actually remember this when I need it again.

Comment: No worries. I just added the selection to highlight that when you have lots of properties, you'll have to view them all via Format-List -Force to see them all and later select as needed. Especaily since you can return hidden properties as well. See: https://sid-500.com/2020/07/28/powershell-show-hidden-properties-from-an-object/ For what you are using, there are only 3 properties, so, correct moot for that effort.